# Basin of attraction of the Lorenz attractor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, basins-of-attraction

What exactly is the basin of attraction of the classical [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) with standard parameter values?

I often read that "almost all" trajectory starting values do tend to the [Lorenz attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system). Which starting values are excluded and why?

Comment: See Wikipedia? How hard is it to link to Wikipedia? Or embed the image from Wikipedia?

Comment: I think that the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3317715/does-the-lorenz-attractor-contain-critical-points might at least partially help answer this question :)